# Upload frozen, [using FTPClient of commons-net]

Tags: upload, ftp-client

I'm using the FTPClient to upload local files, but now there is a bug I don't know how to fix.

here is the code:

```
public UploadStatus uploadFile(String remoteFile,File localFile,FTPClient ftpClient,long remoteSize) throws IOException{  
        UploadStatus status;
        long step = localFile.length() / 100;  
        long process = 0;  
        long localreadbytes = 0L;  
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(localFile,"r");

        //Here is the point, some times, it's frozen here, no reponse from the server.
        OutputStream out = ftpClient.appendFileStream(new String(remoteFile.getBytes("UTF-8"),"iso-8859-1"));  

        //breakpoint resume  
        if(remoteSize>0){  
            ftpClient.setRestartOffset(remoteSize);  
            process = remoteSize /step;  
            raf.seek(remoteSize);  
            localreadbytes = remoteSize;  
        }  
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];  
        int c;  
        while((c = raf.read(bytes))!= -1){  
            out.write(bytes,0,c);  
            localreadbytes+=c;  
            if(localreadbytes / step != process){  
                process = localreadbytes / step;  
                System.out.println("progress:" + process);  
                //TODO call the progressbar function here 
            }  
        }  
        out.flush();  
        raf.close();  
        out.close();  
        boolean result =ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
}
```

For the following line,

```
OutputStream out = ftpClient.appendFileStream(new String(remoteFile.getBytes("UTF-8"),"iso-8859-1"));
```

It works sometimes good, sometimes bad.
upload a new file that no exist in the server, it maybe works well, and to 100%, but some times upload a part of the file, then frozen. (e.g. 45%), 
I debug the code, found it, because [`ftpClient.appendFileStream`] no response.

Thanks .